# Load Laravel routing from external xml, yaml file

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

It looks like Laravel still uses Symfony Routing under the hood. Currently the only way (as for as I know) to load routes is to create a api/web.php file in routes/ folder. My question is is there a way to use Symfony's XmlFileLoader and YamlFile loader to load route collection in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not use Symfony under the hood for routing.

If you wanted to load in a yaml file to provide your own config that shouldn't be too difficult with the Symfony yaml package, then have a look at modifying the `RouteServiceProvider` class in `/app/Providers`.

Comment: I still see the dependency here "symfony/routing": "~3.2". That's why thought it still would be, but I see Laravel has its own RouteCollection class.   I am exploring Symfony's XML file loader, but that returns Symfonys RouteCollection wich may not be compatible with that of Laravel's. Do you think I can some how re-use Symfony's XMLFileLoader here?

Comment: You can write whatever code you want in the RouteServiceProvider, all it does is include a routes.php file.

Comment: Ok I think to be getting there, but do you know what exactly this piece of code is doing in RouteServiceProvider? if (method_exists($this, 'map')) {
            $this->app->call([$this, 'map']);
        }

Comment: Ok I get that now. I will give it a go and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use packages:

### Yaml routing

https://github.com/siokas/laryr

### Annotations routing

https://github.com/LaravelCollective/annotations